# Xpath for Android element using Appium

Tags: android, xpath, appium, robotframework

I am new to automation. I am working on Android + Robot Framework + Appium. I am trying to get access to this 3 locators on the picture, but nothing seems to work.
[image: screenshot from UI Automator Viewer]

As you can see, some of them even don't have an id or any other elements, so I guess I should use xpath to access them, but there is so many layers...

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: you can get it using `Appium Inspector`

Comment: But Appium Inspector doesn't provide xpaths for locator, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are using Appium Inspector only.

But you can certainly find the `X-Path` to an element using it (image attached) :

[image: Some sample image from web]

Note : This is a random image from web just to depict the x-path is an attribute for elements inspected using Appium Inspector.

---

On the contrary to inspect elements within a `WebView` for an application, I would suggest using

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

on your chrome browser.

Comment: But I work on Windows and my Appium Inspector looks like this: http://appium.io/slate/images/windows-inspector.png

Comment: This Chrome Inspect for Devices looks great, but I stuck here: i.imgur.com/slmCp0y.png as I work on a Genymotion Emulator. And I probably don't have USB driver installed...

Answer (score 3):

The main problem for me was to write a proper xpath, as I didn't know I should use classes for this.

So if I wanted to use classes and their indexes, the correct answer for third view is:

```
xpath=//android.view.View[@index='1']/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index='3']/android.view.View[@index='0']
```

And two previous paths are similar.

Answer (score 2):

You are using windows so, you can use [UIAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) available in *android-sdk/tools* to locate the elements. Here is an image of that tool [image]