# XPATH text set dynamic value base on the language

Tags: selenium, xpath, appium, xcuitest

For example `"//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@text='Accept All']"`
which name 'Accept All' can be changed base on the language, for example, Spanish will change to '`Aceptar todas`'

example :

```
<android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Aceptar todas" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[412,1386][669,1438]" displayed="true" />
```

In this case how to make sure this XPath works with this condition?

Comment: I would need to see bit more HTML structure than what you have shared.

Comment: For example : 
</android.view.View>
<android.view.View index="5" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="" >
  <android.view.View index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.view.View" text="" content-desc="Aceptar todas" resource-id="accept-cookie-banner-label" >
    <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Aceptar todas" />
  </android.view.View>
  </android.view.View>
</android.view.View>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the language string as parameter.
You didn't mention what language you are using, so I will use Java here, but this can be done with any other language similarly.
Let's say we are passing the language as `language` string parameter.

```
String xpathTemplate = "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[text()='%s']";
String xpath = String.format(xpathTemplate,language);
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, really helpful. The issue here is that the language quite random and the value also not under control.

Comment: depends the language the phone is using , something it returns text="Aceptar todas" as above example shows as spainish and sometime shows in english text="Accept All" etc.  The approach for you its great , but it will have to manually set the language value instead of programmatically detect

Comment: So, you mean the `name` attribute value is dynamically changing? In this case you should base your locator on something else, that is not being changed without your control

Comment: <android.widget.TextView index="0" package="com.android.chrome" class="android.widget.TextView" text="Aceptar todas" checkable="false" checked="false" clickable="false" enabled="true" focusable="false" focused="false" long-clickable="false" password="false" scrollable="false" selected="false" bounds="[412,1386][669,1438]" displayed="true" />
yep ,  this is the page source and is the only way to detect that element. the pity things is that the text field value is dynamically changing,  I can "//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@name='Accept All']"  it works in english , but in spainish it will fail

Comment: BTW... there is no name attribute on that element. You all are referring to `text`.

Comment: yes , sorry, its text , apology and I updated the question

Comment: Possibly you can uniquely identify that element on dependence of some unique parent element

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like

```
//android.widget.TextView[@index='0'] or //android.widget.TextView[0]
```

here is reference : [Xpath for Android element using Appium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703690/xpath-for-android-element-using-appium?rq=1)